# Disable button2 if button1 is not clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to disable the button2 if button1 is not clicked, and enable it when button1 is clicked. The problem is, the button2 is disable even I already clicked the button1. I don't receive any error, I'm using Swift4 in Xcode10.

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var btn1: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var btn2: UIButton!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     intro()

     btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "checked.png"), for: .selected)
     btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "unchecked.png"), for: .normal)
  }

  @IBAction func button1(_ sender: UIButton) {
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.1, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
    }) { (success) in
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.1, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
            sender.transform = .identity
        }, completion: nil)
      }
   }



   func intro() {
      if btn1.isSelected == true {
        btn2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
      } else {
        btn2.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
      }
   }

}
```

I also tried this code:

```
func intro() {
    if btn1.isTouchInside == true {
      btn2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    } else {
      btn2.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please complete your question

Answer (score 0):

Add any of the below code in your `viewDidLoad()`

```
 btn2.isEnabled = false
```

or

```
btn2.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

and change your button action as,

```
@IBAction func button1(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if btn1.isSelected == true {
      btn2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    } else {
      btn2.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first you want button2 is disable and when you click on the button1 its should be enable.

For this make

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "checked.png"), for: .selected)
     btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "unchecked.png"), for: .normal)
     btn2.isenable = false

   }

 @IBAction func button1(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.isSelected == true 
        {
         btn2.isenable = true
        }
       else 
       {
         btn2.isenable = false
        }

   }
```